# Does BTC.com support ASICBOOST

Tags: mining-pools, antminer, asicboost

Does the www.btc.com pool support Asic Boost? Does it have to support it for me to use Asic Boost on it? If it doesn't support Asic Boost which pools do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe mining Bitcoin with overt (version-rolling) ASICBoost is currently (may 2018) supported by Slushpool, Ckpool, F2pool and my own pool Bitminter.

I would expect this list to keep growing, although adoption has been very slow for some reason.